# Customize a gtable (coordinates and colours)

Tags: r, gridextra, gtable

I'm trying to plot a table inside an image of several graphs with gtable and gridExtra. This is my code and the table I get:

```
g  <- tableGrob(table, rows=NULL)
g  <- gtable_add_grob(g,
                 grobs = rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA, lwd = 2)),                      
                 t = 2, b = nrow(g), l = 1, r = ncol(g))
g  <- gtable_add_grob(g,
                 grobs = rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = NA, lwd = 2)),
                 t = 1, l = 1, r = ncol(g))
grid.draw(g)
```

[image: Here's my table]

I would like to assign coordinates when I plot that table, I put a `par` line before that for my graph and there is a gap in my image, how can I assign coordinates to put the table there? Is there a way to do that like when plotting a legend for example? 
I would like as well to change the colour of the background but I don't manage with grid.draw.

I manage to do all this with grid.table and the theme but then I needed to draw the borders and separators as well as delete the row names, which I didn't manage with grid.table but it worked with grid.draw.

Any ideas to help or where to look? Thanks!